# ¿Cómo debugar un jar externo con Eclipse?

Tags: java, jar

Quiero debugar un jar externo (una applet) en runtime. El jar está en el proyecto (proyecto Maven), en la carpeta src.
La aplicación se ejecuta en un servidor WebLogic y el applet en el cliente (en este caso ambos son mi pc)

No tengo las clases java, pero lo he descompilado con [jd-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512066/how-to-get-java-decompiler-jd-jd-eclipse-running-in-eclipse-helios) y parece estar todo. El jar se ejecuta desde una jsp.

**He intentado:**

- Añadirlo al Build Path del proyecto mediante:

  right_click on project --> properties --> Java Build Path 
  --> Libraries tab --> Add Jars --> Selecciono el mismo jar que hay en el proyecto
  --> Abrir desplegable --> Source Attachment --> Edit
  --> Probé añadiendo el .zip (fuera y dentro del workspace)con las clases generadas

  He añadido los breakpoints donde los necesito, pero no para en ninguno.
- Instalar el plugin [JD-Eclipse](http://jd.benow.ca/) (siguiendo este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512066/how-to-get-java-decompiler-jd-jd-eclipse-running-in-eclipse-helios)) que me muestra el codigo de los .class . He marcado los breakpoints directamente en los .class y tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer debug remoto da lo mismo que sea un applet, una aplicación standalone o un servidor de aplicaciones. 
Necesitas que la JVM (la que ejecute el applet), se ejecute con unos parámetros determinados que permitan al IDE conectarse.

Básicamente, necesitas buscar las propiedades de ejecución del plugin Java (en la pestaña Java de Java Control Panel - javacpl.exe -) y añadirle estos parámetros:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=xxxxx,suspend=n
```

Donde xxxxx es el puerto que estará escuchando JVM para aceptar conexiones de debug.

A continuación, lo que debes hacer es, en Eclipse, ir a:
`Debug -> Debug configurations -> Remote Java Application` y ahí defines una nueva configuración:

1. Pestaña Connect

   - **Connection type:** lo dejas a Standard(Socket Attach).
   - **Host:** el pc al que se va a conectar.
   - **Port:** es mismo que el anterior.
2. Pestaña Source

   - **Add:** añades el codigo fuente (ficheros .java), estén donde estén.

Finalmente, ejecuta primero el applet y sin llegar a abrirlo (para que solo se abra la JVM) ejecuta el **Debug** en **Remote Java Application** en el IDE.

Comment: Ok ya tengo Remote Java Application y el plugin Java (con java control panel) con el mismo puerto. Tengo Weblogic corriendo en un puerto y el plugin Java en otro. Cuando abro el applet desde el cliente, se queda colgado el navegador. ¿Qué puede ser? Trabajo con IE11

Comment: Varias cosas a comprobar: ¿seguro que has puesto el suspend=n? Si no lo pones, el comportamiento sería como indicas. ¿Has probado, aunque sólo sea por validar, con otro navegador? ¿Has activado la opción de mostrar la consola de Java para ver si muestra algo de interés en ella?

Comment: Lo consegui. Ya fuciona.